# Zend Framework 2: Nested child routes vs optional segments with RegEx? How to handle wrong paths?

Tags: php, zend-framework2, url-routing

In Zend Framework 2, I want to be able to create a route structure like this:

```
/list -> literal, will always be "list"
/list/industry -> segment, can be stuff like "private", "non-profit", "governmental "
/list/industry/type -> segment, can be stuff like "plumbing", "medical", "food"…
/list/industry/type/company -> segment, can be stuff like "Joe's plumbig", "Sally's Bakery"…
```

The route can end after every part, which means every line in the explanation above should represent a valid route.

To solve this, I came up with two possible solutions:

**1.** Using one literal route (`/list`) with 4 recursively nested child routes. Stripped down example of what I mean:

```
'list' => array(
    'type' => 'literal',
    'options' => array(
        'route' => '/list',
        'defaults' => array(
            'action' => 'list'
        ),
    ),
    'may_terminate' => true,
    'child_routes' => array(
        'industry' => array(
            'type' => 'segment',
            'options' => array(
                'route' => '/:industry',
                'defaults' => array(
                    'action' => 'industry'
                ),
            ),
            'may_terminate' => true,
            'child_routes' => array(
                'company-type' => array(
                    'type' => 'segment',
                    'options' => array(
                        'route' => '/:type',
                        'defaults' => array(
                            'action' => 'industry'
                        ),
                    ),
                    'may_terminate' => true,
                    'child_routes' => array(
                        'company' => array(
                            'type' => 'segment',
                            'options' => array(
                                'route' => '/:company',
                                'defaults' => array(
                                    'action' => 'industry'
                                ),
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
)
```

I am *really* not sure if this is a proper way of doing it. What I would like about this approach is that I could use different actions.

**2.** Using only one child route, but optional segments:

```
'list' => array(
    'type' => 'literal',
    'options' => array(
        'route' => '/list'
    ),
    'may_terminate' => true,
    'child_routes' => array(
        'my-child-route' => array(
            'type' => 'segment',
            'options' => array(
                'route' => '[/:industry[/:type[/:company]]]',
            ),
        ),
    ),
)
```

While the second idea's config looks much more maintainable, I suspect that the controller/action structure will be messy, because if I am not mistaken, one action needs to handle all segment parts with this structure, so I could either use `'defaults'` to specify this action, or do it like this:

```
'options' => array(
    'route' => '[/:action[/:type[/:company]]]',
    'constraints' => array(
        'artist' => '[industry]+'
    ),
),
```

Inside the `industryAction()`, I then would need to do something like this (pseudo code):

```
if ($this->params['company']) {
    // …
} elseif ($this->params['type']) {
    // …
}
```

In this case, I am not sure how to handle wrong URLs like `/list/private/plumbing/sallys-bakery` – what if Sally's Bakery exists, but obviously not under "plumbing".

So you see, I have some ideas how such route structure could be build, but I am not sure if they are any good or how to approach this further.

What is the recommended way to build such an route structure in Zend Framework 2?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything wrong with your first approach:

- The three possible routes point to different data being displayed (in terms of data type)
- As you already stated, you can (and should) use different actions, or event controllers (which I'd do), keeping your actions clean of routing logic (`if/else`)
- The controller/action is independent of the route and only focuses on one task (e.g. display company details)
- I actually do disagree on the argument that the 2nd is more maintainable. For example you can't add different branches further up the route (e.g. `industry/location/company`).

While writing, I some questions popped my mind though:

- Apparently every company can only be located on exactly one route branch. But what happens if a company is listed in two different industries or types? Are they accessible from the both? This can quickly result on duplicate content on different URIs (which contradicts the `Unique` Identifier part and is really bad for search engine ranking).
- Maybe it might be better to implement this slightly different, with only two routes: one for listing companies (optionally by search criteria, be it as query args or as optional route fragments), and one for listing the company's details. This would result in two very clean controllers, one for listing (incl. filtering), one for details.

This is of course without knowing your requirements and further plans and probably a matter of preference as well.